# Python pass variable to called script | global name 'uid' is not defined

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to build a Rfid card reader on rasberry pi. I'm using python script to read the card and get card UID and then process with other functions and etc but I hit a wall when passing a variable,

My code:

```
    import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
    import MFRC522
    import signal
    import time
    import datetime
    import socket
    import run

    device = (socket.gethostname()) # Define Device name
    # Define logfile Long version |
    logfile = "/home/piadmin/MFRC522-python/" + device + ".csv"
    # logfile = device + ".csv"
    continue_reading = True

    # Capture SIGINT for cleanup when the script is aborted
    def end_read(signal,frame):
            global continue_reading
            print "Ctrl+C captured, ending read."
            continue_reading = False
            GPIO.cleanup()

    # Hook the SIGINT
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, end_read)

    # Create an object of the class MFRC522
    MIFAREReader = MFRC522.MFRC522()

    # Welcome message
    print "Waiting for card to read.."
    print "Press Ctrl-C to stop."

    # This loop keeps checking for chips. If one is near it will get the UID and authenticate
    while continue_reading:
            # Scan for cards
            status, TagType = MIFAREReader.MFRC522_Request(MIFAREReader.PICC_REQIDL)
            # If a card is found
            if status == MIFAREReader.MI_OK:
                    print "Card detected"
                    # Get the UID of the card
                    status,uid = MIFAREReader.MFRC522_Anticoll()
                    print uid
                    time.sleep (1)
                    run.run()
```

And run.py WIP which is called in above code at the last line:

```
    idlist = file('/home/piadmin/temp/idlist.txt') # known ID list
    inlog = file('/home/piadmin/temp/in.txt') # IN log
    status = 'None'

    def checkid():
            for line in idlist:
                    if uid in line:
                            return True
            else:
                    return False
    def checkin():
            for line in inlog:
                    if uid in line:
                            return True
            else:
                    return False

    #uid = raw_input("Please enter uid: ")
    #print "uid ->", uid

    def run():
            if checkid() == True:
                    print 'id = true'
                    if checkin() == True:
                            print 'in = true'
                            print 'set OUT'
                            status = 'OUT'
                            f = open('in.txt','r+')
                            d = f.read().splitlines()
                            f.seek(0)
                            for i in d:
                                    if i != uid:
                                            f.write(i)
                                            f.write('\n')
                            f.truncate()
                            f.close()
                            return True
                    else:
                            print 'in = false, set IN'
                            status = 'IN'
                            f = open('in.txt','a')
                            f.write(str(uid))
                            f.write('\n')
                            f.flush()
                            f.close()
                            return True
            else:
                    print 'check id not true, not checking more (finger)'
                    return False
```

Output I get once code is executed:

```
    Waiting for card to read..
    Press Ctrl-C to stop.
    Card detected
    [101, 116, 172, 79, 242]
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "read.py", line 49, in <module>
        run.run()
      File "/home/piadmin/work/run.py", line 26, in run
        if checkid() == True:
      File "/home/piadmin/work/run.py", line 11, in checkid
        if uid in line:
    NameError: global name 'uid' is not defined
```

I can't figure it out why "NameError: global name 'uid' is not defined" occurs and how to properly pass uid value which is assigned on each loop pass.

Answer (score 0):

Where you define the variable uid?
if the global variable "uid" defined in a module, 
you can access from others modules with this command:

```
theNameOfModuleWhichDefineUID.uid
```

**EDIT:**

For example if global variable "uid" is defined in module "iammodule"
you can access with this command:

```
import iammodule    
print(iammodule.uid)
```

or

```
from iammodule import *
print(uid)
```

Comment: Ok so i'm using https://github.com/mxgxw/MFRC522-python/blob/master/MFRC522.py for instruction for raspberry to read the card.

I guess  you are asking about this part from MFRC522.py
"def MFRC522_DumpClassic1K(self, key, uid):"
As far as I understand my while loop kicks in a reading loop until status change = card gets read, status and uid are assigned in line
  status,uid = MIFAREReader.MFRC522_Anticoll() .
The idea is that uid stays the same for that loop pass and once new card is read, new uid is defined. I want to pass the uid to next function in the same pass if tha makes sense.